# Use Python to modify an E-Mail (email.Message) and add an attachment

Tags: python, email, attachment, mime, multipart

I am reading a mail from stdin using

```
message = mailbox.email.message_from_file(sys.stdin)
```

and want to add an text file attachment. I tried the following:

```
new_msg = email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart('related')

old_msg = email.mime.message.MIMEMessage(message)
new_msg.attach(old_msg)

att_msg = email.mime.text.MIMEText("Textfile attachment")
att_msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename= 'my_attachment.txt')
new_msg.attach(att_msg)

maildir.add(new_msg)
```

where `maildir = mailbox.Maildir('~/mail')`.

However, I get a message in `~/mail` with two attachments `ForwardedMessage.eml` and `my_attachment.txt`.

My goal is to have the original message (with the same headers), but with the text file attached.

**EDIT** Let me give you an example. Original message:

```
To: foo@bar.com
From: User <user@mydomain.net>
Message-ID: <56F2AAD2.7030408@mydomain.net>
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 15:40:18 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Testmessage
```

With my code:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="===============7892775444970429949=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============7892775444970429949==
Content-Type: message/rfc822
MIME-Version: 1.0

To: foo@bar.com
From: User <user@mydomain.net>
Message-ID: <56F2AAD2.7030408@mydomain.net>
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 15:40:18 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Testmessage

--===============7892775444970429949==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="atach.txt"

Textfile attachment
--===============7892775444970429949==--
```

And this is what Thunderbird gives me (and what I want):

```
To: foo@bar.com
From: User <user@mydomain.net>
Message-ID: <56F2AAD2.7030408@mydomain.net>
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 15:40:18 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="------------010607020403070301060303"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------010607020403070301060303
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Testmessage

--------------010607020403070301060303
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="atach.txt"

Textfile attachment
--------------010607020403070301060303--
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried out your code and it works perfect I will provide the working solution. I think it is better to import the needed module classes as sole classes for use in the code. As shown here

```
import sys
import mailbox
import email
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.message import MIMEMessage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

message = mailbox.email.message_from_file(sys.stdin)
maildir = mailbox.Maildir('./mail',create=True)
new_msg = MIMEMultipart('related')

old_msg = MIMEMessage(message)
new_msg.attach(old_msg)

att_msg = MIMEText("Textfile attachment")
att_msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',filename='atach.txt')
new_msg.attach(att_msg)

maildir.add(new_msg)
```

I have also passed an extra keyword arg to create the mailbox if it does not exist. **create=True**.

running the above and checking the mail Dir gives me the following I hope that is what you desire.

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="===============2731426334901210480=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============2731426334901210480==
Content-Type: message/rfc822
MIME-Version: 1.0


Hello trial 2

--===============2731426334901210480==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="atach.txt"

Textfile attachment
--===============2731426334901210480==--
```

Comment: Yes, the code gives me a message as yours. However, both mutt and Thunderbird displays a message with _two_ attachments: the original message and the textfile.